# In the Instagram API for a feed post, is it possible to include tags and X/Y coordinates for those tag?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm looking to share an image from my app to a user's Instagram feed. So I'm looking to integrate with Instagram's API. The image that the user shares will also include tags to other Instagram accounts, and X/Y coordinates for where those tags show up in the Instagram post. But does Instagram's API accept tags and coordinates?

Comment: I feel like you need to explain what/where/why X,Y coordinates are before anyone can answer this ... are you saying you want to include their geo location in the photo?  Because that's built into most image specs already...

Comment: Sure, my application will know the location (X/Y coordinates) of each piece of clothing in an image. My application will also know all of the retailers for each piece of clothing. I'd like my users to be able to share the photo directly to Instagram, and our database will translate each retailer directly to the retailer's Instagram handle. So I'd basically like to auto-tag the image, so it's ready for immediate posting on Instagram.

For example, check out this IG post and click on it to see where all the tags are: https://www.instagram.com/p/BtjoXgcBdhQ/